# How can I modify login error message in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6, my project is working fine, but when I enter wrong login details, I am getting an error.

> These credentials do not match our records.

How I can `modify this error message` and provide my `custom message` if there's an error in the user name or password. I tried to find this message in `LoginController` and Laravel `vendor folder`, but I couldn't find it. Can anyone please tell me the exact location of that file where this error message is located?

Comment: resources/lang/en/auth.php

Comment: Your IDE must have "search in path/project" feature...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i am using sublime and atom, any package or IDE suggetion?

Comment: Sublime has this feature. No need for a change

Comment: yes Thanks, i tried to search by go to anywhere but i couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it in `/resources/lang/en/auth.php`.

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are used during authentication for various
    | messages that we need to display to the user. You are free to modify
    | these language lines according to your application's requirements.
    |
    */

    'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',

];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find that on this location

```
resources/lang/en/auth.php
```

if you want someting custom and more specific check AuthenticatesUsers.php and override function **sendFailedLoginResponse** in LoginController.php